# Google's OpenIDConnect return a Base64 token that cannot be parsed

Tags: .net, json.net, base64, dotnet-httpclient, openid-connect

As exercise to understand OpenIDConnect, I am trying to [authenticate in my web app with Google following this guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect).

The problem is I cannot read the token that Google sends to my application>

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(codeEx.Id_token);
var token = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

It fails in the first line saying: "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

The doc states: "An ID token is a cryptographically signed JSON object encoded in base 64. "

For obvious reasons I cannot put the token here. I have tried:

- [The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114044/the-input-is-not-a-valid-base-64-string-as-it-contains-a-non-base-64-character)
- Add '=' until the length is multiple of 4.
- All together.

I get the code exchange response, and deserialize it with the NewtonSoft.Json library:

```
  var http = new HttpClient(handler);
  HttpResponseMessage result = await http.PostAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", postData);
  var json = JObject.Parse(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

  if (json.Property("error") != null)
      throw new Exception(json.Property("error").Value.ToString() + ":" + json.Property("error_description").Value.ToString());

  var codeEx = json.ToObject<CodeExchangeResponse>();
```

I don´t know if there is any potential issue with the encoding. I can see several ´-´and ´_´in the token.

Any idea about how to read the token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `base64url` decoding (instead of plain `base64`) after deserialization of the compact representation of the token as in:

```
var http = new HttpClient(handler);
var result = await http.PostAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", postData);
var json = JObject.Parse(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
var payload = json.id_token.split('.')[1];
payload = payload.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
var base64 = payload.PadRight(payload.Length + (4 - payload.Length % 4) % 4, '=');
var token = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

Comment: A good alternative for unpacking id_tokens is to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler?view=azure-dotnet

Can be used as follows:
`var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();`
`if (tokenHandler.CanReadToken(idToken) == false) { /* handle error */ }`
`var jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(idToken);`
`var email = jwtToken.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "email").Value;`

Answer (score 4):

From [this post](http://blog.davidchristiansen.com/2012/07/how-simple-is-a-openid-connect-basic-client-c):

> “id_token” is encoded in a format called  JSON Web Token (JWT). JWT is
>   the concatenation of “header”, “body”, “signature” by periods (.).

So you need to split `id_token` on `.` and decode just the 2nd segment:

```
var http = new HttpClient(handler);
var result = await http.PostAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", postData);
var json = JObject.Parse(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
var token = Convert.FromBase64String(json.id_token.split('.')[1]);
```